# Is it possible to unpack a tuple without using variables?

Tags: python, tuples, iterable-unpacking

I'm using the os.path.split() function on a path in my program to get the filename and pathname of a file then passing them into another method, but my current solution seems rather ugly:

```
path = os.path.split(somefile)
some_class(path[0], path[1])
```

Is it possible to unpack the path tuple in a cleaner way within the call to some_class? Something like:

```
some_class(os.path.split(somefile).unpack())
```

Or should I simply be going about this another way? Maybe a more pythonic way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, Python has [argument list unpacking](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). Try this:

```
some_class(*os.path.split(somefile))
```

Comment: a related note: double-asterisk unpacks a dictionary to keyword arguments: `f(**kwargs)`